# Update row and variable in PostgreSQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, sql-update

I have the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE perf
(
startDate DATE,
performance DOUBLE PRECISION,
indexLevel  DOUBLE PRECISION
PRIMARY KEY (startDate)
);
```

The columns `startDate` and `performance` are filled in a previous step. Now I want to set the `indexLevel` in a time-efficient way. In MSSQL this was done like:

```
SET @Index = 100;
UPDATE perf SET @Index = @Index * (1+performance), indexLevel = @Index;
```

How could this be implemented in PostgreSQL?

Is there a better solution than iterating through the table like here: [Iterate through table, perform calculation on each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856984/iterate-through-table-perform-calculation-on-each-row)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired rsults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a cumulative product.  One method uses arithmetic for the calculation:

```
select p.*,
       100 * exp(sum(1 + ln(performance)) over (order by startdate))
from perf p;
```

You can incorporate this into an `update`:

```
update perf p
    set indexLevel as p2.calculated_indexLevel
    from (select p.*,
                 100 * exp(sum(1 + ln(performance)) over (order by startdate)) as calculated_indexLevel
          from perf p
         ) p2
    where p2.startdate = p.startdate
```